# Flutter fade effect at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter

I need to implement this fade effect at the bottom of the screen
[1]: https://dribbble.com/shots/2516959-10th-Week-Wednesday-All-Tasks

I tried to use a `Stack` with the `ListView` and a `Container` at the bottom to reproduce the effect, but the `Container` if it's too high will break the `ListView` scrollability.

My code is below:

```
     Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          const TodosList(),
          Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                    Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              // color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: To make the desired effect you can do only by a Stack as main container then the last child your button BUT before of it putting a container by 50% of height of your screen then putting as background color a linear gradient with 2 colors the first: white of 70% of alpha the second: 0% of alpha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your to do list within ShaderMask

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect rect) {
return LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  colors: [ Colors.transparent, Colors.white],
  //set stops as par your requirement
  stops: [0.0, 1.0], // 50% transparent, 50% white
).createShader(rect);
  },
     blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,

       child:const TodosList(),
)
```